# Directly change an array contained in an array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a about 20 string arrays on which I want to perform the same operation (change specific entries to another value). Therefore I have already written a method:

```
public static void ChangeArray<T>(ref T[,] laoArrOriginal, String lvsToChange, String lvsChangeValue)
{
        int dimRow = laoArrOriginal.GetLength(0);
        int dimCol = laoArrOriginal.GetLength(1);
        for (int i = 0; i < dimRow; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dimCol; j++)
            {
                if (laoArrOriginal[i, j] == lvsToChange)
                {
                    laoArrOriginal[i, j] = lvsChangeValue;
                }
            }
        }       
}
```

Instead of calling 20 times this function with another array name, I thought about creating an array lcsStringArrays of my 20 arrays

```
String[][,] lcsStringArrays = new String[][,]{array1,array2,...}
```

and change them in a for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lcsStringArrays.Length; i++ )
  {
       ChangeArray(ref lcsStringArrays[i], l_dblRecordCount, 1);
  }
```

But after looping the single elements array1, array2, etc. are unaltered while the element lcsStringArrays[i] has the right content.

What I am doing wrong?

EDIT:
I solved this "problem". My code in ChangeArray was wrong. I inserted the code I use now; for the case someone comes here to search for a similar solution.
Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like we need the implementation of ChangeArray method as well. At the high level, I think you are changing the value of the variable (array) passed in. Why would you need this to be `ref` anyways? You are not changing the value of the array itself, you are changing the contents that are held by the array. You don't need `ref` for that purpose.

Comment: I suspect the problem is that `ChangeArray` *is* changing the value of `laoArrOriginal`, which alters the "outer" array without mutation the previous value of the "inner" array object. It's very unclear at the moment though...